# I cannot publish my solution in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I am unable to publish website in visual studio 2010.. My server have changing some where.. so i can't connect with exact domain name. They gave me one **IP address**. But If i put IP Address instead of Target Location in publish method, it is showing an error as following,

`It is not valid disk path or URL. Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Please help me what will do?

Comment: Try to publish locally and then add the website to your host..

Comment: how to publish locally.. i don't know.

Comment: R.Click your website project...
Select **Publish**....
Select Publish Method as **File System** ....
Select A target location....(A local folder)
Then Publish

Comment: after publish to local folder then how to add website ?

Comment: You must copy all the contents and add them to your hosting servers folder.(Note:If you have database connections please consider about the connection strings)
Each hosting vendors may have different settings when hosting. Refer their instructions.